# Mac Qt macdeployqt problems

Tags: macos, qt, macdeployqt

I have 2 load commands in my executable, one is valid the other is now, using qtcreator,macdeployqt load command 12 the versions do not even exist.....

Load command 11
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsasl2.2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 19:00:02 1969
      current version 3.25.0
compatibility version 3.0.0

Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsasl2.2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 19:00:02 1969
      current version 5.9.2
compatibility version 5.9.2